# Parse JS only using JS

Tags: javascript, maps

I have the below JS code which creates like `(47.624718,-122.356133)`

```javascript
var point = new GLatLng(
  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lat\")),
  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute(\"lng\"))
);
```

To only make the value JUST `47.624718 -122.356133` ? how can I use the js `replace()` function to do so?

Comment: Do you want to parse JS, or do you just want to extract some information from a (code-like looking) string?

Comment: What is `point`? The `GLatLng` constructor does not seem to create a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the object methods:

```
point.lat() + ' ' + point.lng()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output = point.lat() + ' ' + point.lng();
```

See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GLatLng

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 chained `replace()` invocations:

```
point = point.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", " ");
```

It will replace the left and right parenthesis with an empty string, and the comma with a single space.

Comment: Or you can use just two replace calls like `point.replace(/\(\)/,'').replace(/,/,' ')`, if you're into golf =)

Comment: @maerics, `/\(\)/` -> `/[()]/g`, and `/,/` -> `/,/g`, no?

Comment: @maerics true, but introducing regex and escape to a JavaScript beginner didn't seem fair to me :)

Comment: @MikeSamuel: ah, definitely.  That's what I get for trying to be cute early in the morning.

Comment: @CodeTalk unless you **really** want to use the `replace` function, you would better use the functions mentionned in the other answers, namely `lat()` and `long()` over the `point` variable, and concatenate the results into a string.